# Can't Pause Storyboard in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView where each item contains two Images defined in a DataTemplate.  When the ListView's SelectedItem changes, I use style triggers to begin storyboards that change the opacity on the two images of the SelectedItem over a total duration of 4 seconds. After the storyboards are complete, I change the SelectedItem to the next item from code so that the same animations occur on the next two images, and so on.

I have a pause button that should pause the storyboards, however it has no effect - the storyboards animation still continue.  I've verified through debugging that the Pause button's click event is called and that the Pause() methods are called on the storyboards.

Here is my UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfTestBase.ViewModel"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestBase"
    xmlns:Custom="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="WpfTestBase.View.ListPresentationView"
    mc:Ignorable="d mc"
    d:DesignHeight="480"
    d:DesignWidth="640"
    >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="PromptStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1">
            </DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="TargetStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1">
            </DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="CombinedStoryboard" Completed="Storyboard_Completed_1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1">
            </DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Style x:Key="CombinedListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ListViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CombinedStoryboard}">
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedDataTemplate">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.25" Source="{Binding PromptUriString}">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PromptStoryboard}">
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Opacity="0.25" Source="{Binding TargetUriString}">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                    AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TargetStoryboard}">
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <ListView x:Name="listViewCombined"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Qs}" 
                  Margin="0" 
                  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                  BorderThickness="4"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQ, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionChanged="listViewCombined_SelectionChanged"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CombinedDataTemplate}"
                  Style="{StaticResource CombinedListViewItemStyle}"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False">
        </ListView>
    </Viewbox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="PauseButton"
                Content="Pause"
                Click="Pause_Click"
                Margin="10"/>
        <Button Name="ResumeButton"
                Content="Resume"
                Click="Resume_Click"
                Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my code-behind:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using WpfTestBase.ViewModel;

namespace WpfTestBase.View
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ListPresentationView
{
    public ListPresentationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ListPresentationViewModel();
    }

    private void listViewCombined_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sbPrompt = FindResource("PromptStoryboard") as Storyboard;
        listViewCombined.BeginStoryboard(sbPrompt);
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as ListPresentationViewModel;
        vm.CombinedAnimationCompletedCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    private void SuspendOrResumeStoryboard(PowerModes mode)
    {
        if (mode == PowerModes.Resume || mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
        {
            var vm = this.DataContext as ListPresentationViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var sbPrompt = FindResource("PromptStoryboard") as Storyboard;
                    var sbTarget = FindResource("TargetStoryboard") as Storyboard;
                    var sbCombined = FindResource("CombinedStoryboard") as Storyboard;

                    if (sbPrompt != null && sbTarget != null)
                    {
                        if (mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
                        {
                            sbPrompt.Pause();
                            sbTarget.Pause();
                            sbCombined.Pause();

                            Console.WriteLine("===PAUSED" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                        }
                        else if (mode == PowerModes.Resume)
                        {
                            sbPrompt.Resume();
                            sbTarget.Resume();
                            sbCombined.Resume();
                            Console.WriteLine("===RESUMED" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendOrResumeStoryboard(PowerModes.Suspend);
    }

    private void Resume_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendOrResumeStoryboard(PowerModes.Resume);
    }
}
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WpfTestBase.Model;

namespace WpfTestBase.ViewModel
{
/// <summary>
/// This class contains properties that a View can data bind to.
/// <para>
/// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
/// </para>
/// </summary>
public class ListPresentationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _currCombinedIndex = 0;
    public List<WmtQ> Qs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedQ" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SelectedQPropertyName = "SelectedQ";

    private WmtQ _selectedQ = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the SelectedQ property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public WmtQ SelectedQ
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedQ;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => SelectedQ, ref _selectedQ, value);

        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _loadedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the LoadedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadedCommand
                ?? (_loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    SelectedQ = Qs[_currCombinedIndex];
                }));
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _combinedAnimationCompletedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the CombinedAnimationCompletedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand CombinedAnimationCompletedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _combinedAnimationCompletedCommand
                ?? (_combinedAnimationCompletedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    _currCombinedIndex++;
                    if (_currCombinedIndex < Qs.Count)
                    {
                        SelectedQ = Qs[_currCombinedIndex];
                    }
                }));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ListPresentationViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public ListPresentationViewModel()
    {
        Qs = new List<WmtQ>();
        var qList = new List<WmtQ> { new WmtQ("One", "A"), new WmtQ("Two", "B"), new WmtQ("Three", "C"), new WmtQ("Four", "D") };
        Qs = qList;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to specify true as the second parameter to Begin to acutally make the storyboard controllable? `sbPrompt.Begin(this, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to redcurry's answer and mm8's comment I solved this by moving the storyboards entirely to code-behind.

My UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CombinedListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedDataTemplate">
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.25" Source="{Binding PromptUriString}"
                   Name="PromptImage">
            </Image>
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Opacity="0.25" Source="{Binding TargetUriString}"
                   Name="TargetImage">
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <ListView x:Name="listViewCombined"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Qs}" 
                  Margin="0" 
                  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                  BorderThickness="4"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQ, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionChanged="listViewCombined_SelectionChanged"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CombinedDataTemplate}"
                  Style="{StaticResource CombinedListViewItemStyle}"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        </ListView>
    </Viewbox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="PauseButton"
                Content="Pause"
                Click="Pause_Click"
                Margin="10"/>
        <Button Name="ResumeButton"
                Content="Resume"
                Click="Resume_Click"
                Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class ListPresentationView
{
    Storyboard sbPrompt;
    Storyboard sbTarget;

    bool _isCompSleep = false;

    List<int> _completedListViewIndices = new List<int>();

    public ListPresentationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ListPresentationViewModel();

        // Needed for controlling storyboards
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterElementsInNameScope();
        AnimateCurrentItem(0);
    }

    private void RegisterElementsInNameScope()
    {
        var gen = listViewCombined.ItemContainerGenerator;
        var obj = (gen.ContainerFromItem(listViewCombined.Items[0]));
        if (obj != null)
        {
            ListViewItem myListBoxItem = (ListViewItem)obj;

            ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

            DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
            Image promptImage = (Image)myDataTemplate.FindName("PromptImage", myContentPresenter);
            Image targetImage = (Image)myDataTemplate.FindName("TargetImage", myContentPresenter);

            this.RegisterName(listViewCombined.Name, listViewCombined);
            this.RegisterName(promptImage.Name, promptImage);
            this.RegisterName(targetImage.Name, targetImage);
        }
    }

    private void AnimateCurrentItem(int currIndex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AnimateCurreintItem, currIndex: " + currIndex);
        var gen = listViewCombined.ItemContainerGenerator;
        var obj = (gen.ContainerFromItem(listViewCombined.Items[currIndex]));
        if (obj != null)
        {
            ListViewItem myListBoxItem = (ListViewItem)obj;

            ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

            DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
            Image promptImage = (Image)myDataTemplate.FindName("PromptImage", myContentPresenter);
            Image targetImage = (Image)myDataTemplate.FindName("TargetImage", myContentPresenter);

            this.UnregisterName(listViewCombined.Name);
            this.UnregisterName(promptImage.Name);
            this.UnregisterName(targetImage.Name);
            this.RegisterName(listViewCombined.Name, listViewCombined);
            this.RegisterName(promptImage.Name, promptImage);
            this.RegisterName(targetImage.Name, targetImage);

            DoubleAnimation promptAni = new DoubleAnimation();
            promptAni.From = 1;
            promptAni.To = 0;
            promptAni.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000));

            sbPrompt = new Storyboard();
            sbPrompt.Children.Add(promptAni);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(promptAni, promptImage.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(promptAni, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));

            DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames targetAni = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            var kf1 = new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0.25, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)));
            var kf2 = new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
            var kf3 = new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0.25, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
            targetAni.KeyFrames.Add(kf1);
            targetAni.KeyFrames.Add(kf2);
            targetAni.KeyFrames.Add(kf3);

            if (sbTarget != null) sbTarget.Completed -= Storyboard_Completed_1;
            sbTarget = new Storyboard();
            sbTarget.Completed += Storyboard_Completed_1;

            sbTarget.Children.Add(targetAni);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(targetAni, targetImage.Name);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(targetAni, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));

            sbPrompt.Begin(this, true);
            sbTarget.Begin(this, true);

        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }

    private void listViewCombined_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lView = sender as ListView;
        if (lView != null)
        {
            var index = lView.SelectedIndex;
            if (index >= 0 && index < lView.Items.Count)
            {
                AnimateCurrentItem(index);
            }
        }
    }

    private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
        where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is childItem)
                return (childItem)child;
            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void Storyboard_Completed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Storyboard_Completed_1 " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        var vm = this.DataContext as ListPresentationViewModel;

        if (!_isCompSleep) vm.CombinedAnimationCompletedCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    private void SuspendOrResumeStoryboard(PowerModes mode)
    {
        if (mode == PowerModes.Resume || mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    if (sbPrompt != null && sbTarget != null)
                    {
                        if (mode == PowerModes.Suspend)
                        {
                            _isCompSleep = true;
                            sbPrompt.Pause(this);
                            sbTarget.Pause(this);
                            Console.WriteLine("===PAUSED" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                        }
                        else if (mode == PowerModes.Resume)
                        {
                            _isCompSleep = false;
                            sbPrompt.Resume(this);
                            sbTarget.Resume(this);
                            Console.WriteLine("===RESUMED" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendOrResumeStoryboard(PowerModes.Suspend);
    }

    private void Resume_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendOrResumeStoryboard(PowerModes.Resume);
    }
}
```

And View-Model:

```
public class ListPresentationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _currCombinedIndex = 0;
    public List<WmtQ> Qs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="SelectedQ" /> property's name.
    /// </summary>
    public const string SelectedQPropertyName = "SelectedQ";

    private WmtQ _selectedQ = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets and gets the SelectedQ property.
    /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
    /// </summary>
    public WmtQ SelectedQ
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedQ;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => SelectedQ, ref _selectedQ, value);

        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _loadedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the LoadedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadedCommand
                ?? (_loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    SelectedQ = Qs[_currCombinedIndex];
                }));
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand _combinedAnimationCompletedCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the CombinedAnimationCompletedCommand.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand CombinedAnimationCompletedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _combinedAnimationCompletedCommand
                ?? (_combinedAnimationCompletedCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    _currCombinedIndex++;
                    if (_currCombinedIndex < Qs.Count)
                    {
                        SelectedQ = Qs[_currCombinedIndex];
                    }
                }));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ListPresentationViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public ListPresentationViewModel()
    {
        Qs = new List<WmtQ>();
        var qList = new List<WmtQ> { new WmtQ("One", "A"), new WmtQ("Two", "B"), new WmtQ("Three", "C"), new WmtQ("Four", "D") };
        Qs = qList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview), it seems like the `BeginStoryboard` tag needs to have a name in order for it to be controllable:

> If you give the BeginStoryboard a name by specifying its Name
>   property, you make it a controllable storyboard. You can then
>   interactively control the storyboard after it's started.

However, I've also read that [some people](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbf9c605-1db1-4017-8847-8e01f89239d0/how-can-i-pause-a-wpf-storyboard-using-c-code-behind?forum=blend) (see answer by Christine L.) have had problems with storyboards when mixing XAML triggers and code-behind. If you can't get it to work, it may be best to either use triggers only or code-behind only but not both.

If you're going to use code-behind, the storyboard needs to be made controllable by specifying `true` for the `IsControllable` parameter when you call the `Begin` method on the `Storyboard`.